# not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, overriding

someone can explain to me why it keeps giving me this error

**error: MyPanel is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
public    class   MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {**

i think i did everything right i can't figure out what i did wrong, this code was for a test to make an image move horizontally

this is my code

Main.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Main {
      
      public static void main(String [] args) {
         
            new MyFrame();
            
            }
       }
```

MyFrame.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame  {
   
   MyPanel panel;
   
   MyFrame(){
            
            panel = new MyPanel();
            
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setSize(1024,720);
            this.add(panel);
            this.pack();
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setVisible(true);
      }

}
```

MyPanel.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public    class   MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {


   final int PANEL_WIDTH = 1024;
   final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 720;
   Image pilota;
   Image backgroundImage;
   Timer timer;
   int xVelocity = 1;
   int yVelocity = 1;
   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;

   MyPanel() {
      this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH,PANEL_HEIGHT));
      this.setBackground(Color.black);
      pilota = new ImageIcon("pilota1.png").getImage();
      timer = new Timer(10,null);
      timer.start();

   }


   public void paint(Graphics g) {

      super.paint(g);
      Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2D.drawImage(pilota, x, y, null);
   }

   public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {

      x = x + xVelocity;
      repaint();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
```

Should be (with two letter 'r's):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

But always add the override notation, so:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

---

Sidebar re:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   super.paint(g);
```

To custom paint any `JComponent` the correct method is:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
```

Of course, also add the override notation.